# SQL Query not giving the desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables

1. tbl_message

   ```
   id | user_id | user_name |message | society_id
   1 -- 252----- Shubham----- HeyHi--------- 3
   2 -- 252----- Shubham----- HeyHi--------- 3
   3 -- 250----- Rahul---------- HeyHi--------- 3
   4 -- 251----- Sachin--------- HeyHi--------- 3
   ```
2. tbl_submessage

   ```
   id | post_id | user_id | submessage
   1-----1----------252---------Hi-
   2-----1----------252---------Hi-
   3-----1----------253---------Hi-
   4-----1----------253---------Hi-
   5-----1----------253---------Hi-
   6-----2----------254---------Hi-
   7-----2----------254---------Hi-
   ```

I have to count the number of submessages in table **tbl_submessage** whose post_id = id of message in **tbl_message**.
Basically tbl_message **contains post of a forum** and tbl_submessage consists of **conversations done within that post**.

I tried the following query.

```
SELECT tk.*,COUNT(tp.id) FROM tbl_message  tk,tbl_submessage  tp WHERE tk.society_id=3 and  tk.id=tp.post_id;
```

This query is returning 
 id | user_id | user_name |message | society_id | COUNT(tp.id)
        1 -- 252----- Shubham----- HeyHi--------- 3 -----------7

What I want is

id | user_id | user_name |message | society_id  | COUNT
        1 -- 252----- Shubham----- HeyHi--------- 3---------5
        2 -- 252----- Shubham----- HeyHi--------- 3---------2
        3 -- 250----- Rahul---------- HeyHi--------- 3---------0
        4 -- 251----- Sachin--------- HeyHi--------- 3---------0

Please help me with the query.

Comment: nothing has to do with the query. in your cpanel, give permission to that user to access and alter this database

Comment: Check your user's privileges and permissions on the the database

Comment: First error: You wrote `tp.COUNT(id)` while you should write `COUNT(tp.id)`.

Comment: @FDavidov I corrected my query and the error is gone but I am not getting the desired result . I guess my query is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your query: you need to change the join to a left join to get users who have no sub-messages and add a GROUP BY to give results on a by user basis. Try this:

```
SELECT tk.*,  COUNT(tp.id) 
FROM tbl_message tk
LEFT JOIN tbl_submessage tp
ON tp.post_id = tk.id
WHERE tk.society_id=3
GROUP BY tk.id
```

Comment: I got the desired result.